# strtoull "seems" to return a wrong value

Tags: c, printf, strtoull

Basically I am trying to convert hex strings into `unsigned long long values` using `strtoull`. Here's the simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main ()
{
    unsigned long long val =0;

    //printf("sizeof(unsigned long long)=%d\n", sizeof(unsigned long long));

    val = strtoull("0x8004298c42ULL",NULL,16);

    printf("%llx\n", val);

    if ( val == 0x8004298c42ULL)
    {
        printf("Success\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect `val` to print `8004298c42` but it prints `4298c42`. The `8` is being chopped off. I tried without the `0x` and without the `ULL` too. But still the same result. Just to make sure that I am not missing out on some trivial `printf` format specifier thing, I even checked the contents of `val`. Still no use( ie Success was not printed )

I think I am missing out something trivial but don't know what!

Comment: The code at ideone (now) uses `<stdlib.h>` instead of `<string.h>`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I changed the file at ideone after your answer. Now that your answer is there, I shall remove the link.

Comment: please read the link: <http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoull>  which among other things states: Since strtoul() can legitimately return 0 or ULONG_MAX (ULLONG_MAX for strtoull()) on both success and failure, the calling program should set errno to 0 before the call, and then determine if an error occurred by checking whether errno has a nonzero value after the call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `strtoull()` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`, not `<string.h>`, so the compiler thinks it returns an `int`, not an `unsigned long long`.

Cure: make sure that all functions are declared before they are used.  If you use `gcc`, then you should consider some combination of `-Wall`, `-Wextra`, `-Wstrict-prototypes`, `-Wmissing-prototypes`, `-Wold-style-declaration`, `-Wold-style-definition` and `-Werror`.

Comment: Oh My! This dint occur to me as the compiler dint complain of implicit declaration. But yea, `-Wall` tells me my mistake

Comment: With just `-Wall` it does: "warning: implicit declaration of function 'strtoull'".

Comment: I don't compile C without that warning — indeed, I almost always use all the ones I listed.  It avoids such problems, and many others too.